# Getting a text field element from table cell in page-object gem

Tags: page-object-gem

I have an application which is mostly tables, so instead of creating cell elements for every cell , i just declare the table. I can then pass in arguments in the tests to locate the required cell. Such as

```
get_text_from_table('Row', 'Column')
```

This works fine for getting text from cells, clicking buttons in cells and getting select lists from cells using code like this

```
the_table_element[row][column].text
the_table_element[row][column].button_element
the_table_element[row][column].select_list_element
```

however

```
the_table_element[row][column].text_field_element
```

will not work

is a different approach needed for text fields or does this functionality not exist for `text_field` for some reason

**update:**

```
admin_campaign_advertiser_table_element[row][column].find_element(:class , 'value')
```

returns the element correctly, which proves i am selecting the right cell, but obviously this is is not coding within the page object gem anymore

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you are looking at the right cell or that the text field is actually there?

Comment: yeah i've tried it on several cells within the table, heres a copy of the html code for a cell to see if this gives any insight

Comment: <td>
<input class="value" maxlength="45" ind="1" value="Petes Test Shop">
</td>

Comment: This appears to be a selenium-webdriver specific issue when dealing with text fields (inputs) without the `type="text"` attribute. For more details see the comments on the page-object gem's [Issue 214](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues/214).